# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in C:\wamp\www\Giusti\AssignmentExample.php on line 24

Tags: php, syntax

I'm teaching myself PHP and doing these projects from the book I have. But I typed the code exactly as shown, and still get the same error. I also have re-checked the code many times. Sorry for being such a noob but I'm really stuck. If someone could explain what's wrong and fix this it would be GREATLY appreciated thanks =)

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0
STRICT//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>php</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type"
    content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
</head>
<body>

<?php
$ChangingVar = 100;
$ChangingVar += 50;
echo "<p>";
echo "Variable after addition assignment =
$ChangingVar<br />";
$ChangingVar -= 30;
echo "Variable after subtraction assignment =
$ChangingVar<br />";
$ChangingVar /= 3;
echo "Variable after division assignment = 
$ChangingVar *= 8;
echo "Variable after multiplication assignment =
$ChangingVar<br />";
$ChangingVar %= 300;
echo "Variable after modulus assignment =
$ChangingVar</p>";


?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a `$ChangingVar<br />";`:

```
$ChangingVar /= 3;
echo "Variable after division assignment = 
$ChangingVar<br />";     // <-- here
$ChangingVar *= 8;
```

Note that line breaks won't be visible on the page, so writing

```
echo "Variable after division assignment = $ChangingVar<br />";
```

might make it easier to read and verify ;)

Answer (score 1):

You make mistake in writing after "$ChangingVar *= 8;". i tried to fix it. Take a look.

```
<?php
$ChangingVar = 100;

$ChangingVar += 50;

echo "<p>";

echo "Variable after addition assignment =

$ChangingVar<br />";

$ChangingVar -= 30;

echo "Variable after subtraction assignment =

$ChangingVar<br />";

$ChangingVar /= 3;

echo "Variable after division assignment =

$ChangingVar<br />";

$ChangingVar *= 8;

echo "Variable after multiplication assignment =

$ChangingVar<br />";

$ChangingVar %= 300;

echo "Variable after modulus assignment =

$ChangingVar</p>";

?>
```